# How do I remove extra space from the image in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I got extra space in firefox, for chrome and safari it works perfectly. The extra space in the under the image. When I resize the firefox browser it will show the extra space. How do I get rid of the extra space? I was testing "box-ordinal-group" to make my image show first and then content second.

my code is:

```css
 img {
   width: 100%;
}
.music-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
}

.poster-content {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  box-ordinal-group: 2;
}

.poster-wrap {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  box-ordinal-group: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="row-wrap">
     <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">
      <div class="poster-wrap">
       <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/420x420/000/fff"> 
      </div>
      <div class="poster-content">
       <h1>Sunday</h1>
       <p>Carefully selected songs to get you in a mellow state of mind after a week of hard work. A perfect mixtape to get ready to chase your dream again on Monday.</p>
       <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="btn">listen now</div>
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="row-wrap">
     <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">
    
      <div class="poster-content">
       <h1>Sunday</h1>
       <p>Carefully selected songs to get you in a mellow state of mind after a week of hard work. A perfect mixtape to get ready to chase your dream again on Monday.</p>
       <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="btn">listen now</div>
       </a>
      </div>
      <div class="poster-wrap">
       <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/420x420/000/fff"> 
      </div> 
     </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: try display block on the img

Comment: You're using a verty old flexbox syntax there...try using the more current version.

Comment: What is the current flexbox syntax?

Comment: display: block doesn't work :( @TomMillard

Comment: If I use the current syntax, will that solve that problem for firefox? what is the current flexbox syntax? Can't find it :( @Paulie_D

Comment: @waisieli I updated my answer with flex example

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use css `flex` which is the "new" version of the `box` you are using. You can learn more at [Css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

```css
img {

  width: 100%;

}

.music-wrapper {

  display: -webkit-box;

  display: -moz-box;

  display: -ms-flexbox;

  display: -webkit-flex;

  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;

}

.poster-content {} .poster-wrap {}
```

```html
<section class="row-wrap">
  <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">
    <div class="poster-wrap">
      <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/420x420/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="poster-content">
      <h1>Sunday 1</h1>
      <p>Carefully selected songs to get you in a mellow state of mind after a week of hard work. A perfect mixtape to get ready to chase your dream again on Monday.</p>
      <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="btn">listen now</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="row-wrap">
  <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">

    <div class="poster-content">
      <h1>Sunday 2</h1>
      <p>Carefully selected songs to get you in a mellow state of mind after a week of hard work. A perfect mixtape to get ready to chase your dream again on Monday.</p>
      <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="btn">listen now</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="poster-wrap">
      <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/420x420/000/fff">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: When I remove it, the second section img doesn't show first. I want the image show first and then content wrapper. I'm testing right now using the structure and change the order in css.

Comment: @waisieli Please check my revised answer. I believe this is what you are actually looking for